# apex default amount of rows per page option

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I set default amount of rows per page for interactive report?

I need this value to be applied for all interactive reports that do not have this value overridden. The reason why I need that is the following: it is cumbersome to set necessary amount of rows for each created interactive report and when it comes to updating that value it becomes a nightmare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For interactive reports, you can modify the default number of rows displayed by selecting the appropriate number of rows and then [saving the report](http://apex.oracle.com/i/doc/TDPAX/interactive_reports.htm) with the option "save as default report settings" (when logged in as an APEX developer).

Unfortunately, this has to be applied to each report.

For a mass update, [a thread on OTN mentions](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=692800):

> There is a display_rows column in the WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_RPTS table in your apex application schema. You can do a global update, where the flow_id equals your app_id.

This has not been verified, use at your own risk (unsupported by Oracle).

Comment: saving report is not an option, that is good for one two reports, but when there should be several reports with the same default amount of rows it is difficult to use it.